# Removing the "X" from Text Box in IE 10(CSS Approach Not Working)

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I have web Page on which there are some textbox, while viewing this page in IE 10 compatibility Mode it displays "X" to clear the field.
From the few posts I got that this "X" can be disabled using the below CSS :

```
input[type=text]::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
```

But this doesn't seem to be working for me.

Please guide to resolve the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Also, use clear:

```
input[type="text"]::-ms-clear, 
input[type="text"]::-ms-reveal 
{  
   display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
display: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ak1a9k0e/)